# Как сменить иконку для moreNavigationController (пятая секция внутри UITabBarController)

Tags: cocoa, objective-c, iphone

Существует ли такая возможность вообще?

Потому как ситуация такая, что все иконки должны подсвечиваться зеленым цветом (иконки нарисованы и прописаны).

Только вот никак не выходит назначить иконку для секции "`More`".
Вариант использовать стандартную или всего 5 секций (то есть без "More") просьба не писать, так как объяснить это заказчику вряд ли удастся (уже пробовали, но все равно надо, так как дизайнер сделал и больше никак - как не уговаривай).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да нашел сам способ как это сделать - вот здесь http://svyat.comixa.net/?p=66 все подробно описал